# при клике на кнопку, форма исчезает (Значение block меняется на none). Как убрать?

Tags: форма

Есть форма, поля и кнопка. при клике на кнопку, форма исчезает (Значение block меняется на none). Получается после отправки данных формы, она у меня исчезает. Как это убрать?

Форма обычная, типовая

```
<form id="promo-form" class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-1 w-25 p-3" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" type="tel" class="form-control">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Нажимая эту кнопку, я даю <a href="soglasie.html" target="_blank">согласие</a> на обработку персональных данных</small>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-info button_submit" id="btn_promo">Заказать сейчас</button>
</form>
```

Причем ниже на странице есть такая же форма, но в модальном окне. Там понятно, окно модальное закрывается, окно благодарности выскакивает и все.  Скрипт на отправку данных из этих форм:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mailer/smart.php",
    data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    $(this).find("input").val("");
    $('form').fadeOut();
    $('.overlay, #thanks').fadeIn('slow');
    $('form').trigger('reset');
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрать `$('form').fadeOut();` в `done`. 
[Вот документация про fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Смурфик Рад что помог.